# Batch Script Over WAN intranet, Without PSEXEC to get Win XP system inormation

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, psexec

I want to remotely (over WAN intranet) access Windows XP system information (i.e. installed program's, logged on user, PC on domain or not, firewall status, services status, etc.) using batch scripting, but I don't want to install any client on remote Windows XP system. I **don't want to use PSEXEC** as it carries passwords in plain text. Can anyone please guide me how can I do this? Don't need guidance for writing the batch script, **but how would I make it work over WAN intranet?**

Answer (score 0):

Most commands can work on other computers.See

```
systeminfo /s \\computername
```

or

```
wmic /node:computernameorip computersystem get
```

Look at help on both commands. If you are an admin on remote system you don't need a username or password. Esp see `wmic /?` to get some (have to read docs for less common things) the thousands of things you can query.

Also wmic can run batchfiles or programs on other computers. Asit uses C parsing backslashes must be escaped.

```
wmic process call create "c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe"
```

Commands on remote computers are invisible (but not locally).

See `wmic process call /?` and `wmic process call create /?`.